# msbuild task to remove all sub directories with a particular name

Tags: msbuild

I want a msbuild task to remove all sub-directories with a specified name, I tried this but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Main" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <directory></directory>
        <subDirectory></subDirectory>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Main">
        <RemoveDir Directories="$(directory)\**\subDirectory\*" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why is there no values in the "directory* property and "subdirectory" property?

Comment: when using the task they are passed as command line parameters